# How can I find the x-corresponding value of a function?

Tags: python

I have a function (Moorse potential in case anybody cares), and I want to find the coordinates of the minimum value in X. I can very easily find the minimum value in y with `min(y)`, but, how can I find the x value asociated witgh the minimum y coordinate?

Copy of my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import math
from math import e

#para niquel

D= 0.4205 #profundidad de pozo
f = 2.7540 #distancia de equilibrio
a = 1.4199 #ancho de potencial
x = np.arange(-100,100,0.01) #Distancia interatómica / eje X
y = -D + D*(1-e**(-a*(x-f)))**2


plt.xlabel('Distancia interatómica [$\AA$]')
plt.ylabel('Energía [eV]')
plt.plot(x, y, color = 'mediumturquoise')
plt.xlim(2,5.5)
plt.ylim(-0.5, 0.75)
#plt.annotate('a$_{0}$', xy = (X, min(y)) ) HERE'S WHERE I'D NEED THE X COORDINATE!!

plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an argmin to find the minimum index of y, then based on how you generated the range, you can work backwards to get the actual value. You can do something like

```
x[np.argmin(y)]
```

Note that this might not be equivalent to

```
np.argmin(y) * 0.01 + -100
```

due to floating point rounding issues.

Answer (score 0):

With some algebra (or a graphing calculator...) you can resolve the Morse Potential equation in terms of y and get an accurate and quick answer.

I went ahead and did this ([using symbolab, you can confirm here](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/derivative-calculator/solve%20for%20x%2C%20y%3D%5Cleft(0.4205%5Ccdot%5Cleft(1%20-%20e%5E%7B%5Cleft(-1.4199%5Cleft(x-2.754%5Cright)%5Cright)%7D%5Cright)%5E%7B2%7D%5Cright))) given your constants, and then plotted the graphs [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8s2wnnapb9) to confirm they looked right. There are two mathematical functions due to the two cases arising when taking the square root.

Here's some code that should compute the x value based off the y value:

```
import math

def getXfromY(y):
    if(y <= 2.754):
        return -(math.ln(-math.sqrt(y/0.4205) + 1))/1.4199
    elif(y > 2.754):
        return -(math.ln(math.sqrt(y/0.4205) + 1))/1.4199
```